# Laravel: Install git, composer, nodejs and gulp on production server

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, deployment, continuous-deployment

Is there a right or proper way of deploying a laravel application? This is because I am not sure if it is right to install git, composer, nodejs and gulp on production server.

I have these installed on my development server so I just do a `git checkout development && git pull` to get updates then run `gulp --production` to compile assets as I have set the public to ignore list on git.

The composer is to do `composer install` should I have updates on the `composer.json` file.

Is this setup the right way to also do in production?

Comment: This isn't really a suitable question for SO, since it's about a best practice rather than a programming problem. However, it's still a very good question, so I recommend that you post on e.g. the Laracasts forums or in the Laravel subreddit. Good luck!

Comment: Nothing wrong with having git installed on a production server for deployment purposes, however committing and pushing changes to git from that server is probably not a good idea.

Comment: keywords : continuous integration for laravel projects